# preg_replace()Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: preg-match, php

I have this code :

```
function queryString(){ 
    //matches up to 10 digits in page number
    $query_string = eregi_replace("page=[0-9]    {0,10}&","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    return $query_string;
}
```

and when im run it returns this error:
    Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Hi there, the error message should tell you everything you needed to solve the problem. Generally Stack overflow is here to help when your own research and attempts to solve the issue have failed, rather than as a replacement for the functions man page or a search engine.

Comment: Show us real code. The warning tells `preg_match...` but your code shows `eregi_replace...`.

Answer (score 12):

If you were to use preg_replace, you need a starting and an ending delimiter

```
$query_string = preg_replace("/page=[0-9]    {0,10}&/","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
                              ^                     ^
```